# CMS inside a grails app

Tags: grails, content-management-system

i'm trying to build a very simple CMS functionality within a grails app.
Basically what I'm trying here is having a gsp in a string and I would like to build the gsp from this string.

It works, but the resulting page is not decorated with the main layout.
Furthermore in some other tries I noticed that model passed to the make method is ignored.

I'm using grails 2.0.1.

Thanks

```
class HomeController {

    def groovyPagesTemplateEngine

    def cms() {
        def page = """<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>CMS page using your application's main layout</title>
</head>
<body>
CMS page using your application's "main" layout.
</body>
</html>"""

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)

        groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(page, "somepage.gsp").make([nome: "ciao"]).writeTo(pw)
        render sw
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to try this? Have you seen Weceem http://www.weceem.org/
It integrates really nicely with Grails...

Comment: you're right. i checked it out but what i wanted to achieve here was getting this experiment to work. in the meanwhile i'll try weceem as I heard a lot good so far

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work because you're essentially just calling render with a string.

The layout gets applied when the sitemesh filter gets called. In order to get this to work, you would have to get the sitemesh decorators applied to your string.

When we were building a similar feature, all we did was to send the relevant page fragments:

i.e,

Mytemplate.gsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="layout" content="${layout}"/>
${head}
</head>
<body>
${body}
</body>
</html>
```

and then you can just call:

```
render( template: 'MyTemplate', model:[ layout: 'layout', head: '...', body: '...' ] )
```

This has the same effect of what you're trying to do but with the addition of sitemesh ( and potentially plugins integrating correctly ).

Comment: I get your point. But in your example you can call render because your template is on filesystem. Is there a way to call render (and the sitemesh filter indeed) with the template inside a string (coming from a database for example) and having it decorated ?

Comment: For deeper clarification: i want to store gsp in a database, and I want to render it with layout decoration. So far seems this is not possible anymore...

Comment: You probably can. Look at the code for the applyLayout tag - http://grails.org/doc/1.1/ref/Tags/applyLayout.html# - you'll see that there are additional calls to the decorator. However, your decorator chain is not set in the gsp. You might either need to move rendering down the filter chain ( via an interceptor or filter ) or replicate the functionality of the sitemesh filter. My solution offers a simple workaround for this.

Comment: You mean just having a template on filesystem and the passing in body variable via model, taken from database or whatever ?

Comment: Your solution doesn't allow to include taglib calls into the body as they're not been interpreted